# DisplayPort stopped working - nVidia Geforce 660 Ti on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport

I have a computer with 3 monitors connected to my nVidia Geforce 660 Ti graphics card.
I had to move the computer across the room the other day, and after the move the one monitor connected using DisplayPort refuses to show anything.

**Details**

GigaByte motherboard (Intel Core i5 & 8 GB memory) , nVidia GeForce 660 Ti with 2 GB memory.

Monitor #1: 27" connected to the graphics card using DVI-D.

Monitor #2: 19" (VGA output only) connected to the DVI-I port on the graphics card using a VGA-to-DVI adapter.

Monitor #3: 19" (same model as monitor 2) connected to DisplayPort on the graphics card suing a VGA cable and a DisplayPort adapter.

The setup did work before the move.

Here is what I tried:

1. Switched the two 19" monitors, that proved that the monitors are
   both good. The one connected using DisplayPort is always the one not
   showing anything.
2. Replaced the VGA cable between the graphics card and the DisplayPort adapter.

If I power-cycle the monitor, the Acer logo (it's an Acer monitor) comes up, the power light is green, but after a few seconds the power light goes yellow and the message "no signal" shows up on the monitor.
If I unplug the DisplayPort adapter when the computer is running, and then plug it in again, the monitor flickers a bit (no real picture, though, just a different shade of black) and the light goes green for a little bit. Then it goes yellow and the "no signal" message shows up.

When I look in Windows display properties or nVidia Control Panel, only the two first monitors show up. Windows simply refuses to see the last monitor.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I replaced the DisplayPort-to-VGA adapter and it worked.
No idea why unplugging the old one and plugging it in again would break it...

Comment: You can accept your own answer. This will prevent it frm getting bumped from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of a monitor connected with DP which stopped working, with a "no signal" error after a few months of normal function. The computer though did detect the presence of the monitor, and using another entrance port on the monitor it did work (e.g. VGA or DVI).

Following [this](https://evert.meulie.net/2015/01/25/no-signal-displayport-fix/) I unplugged the power for a few minutes and the monitor was again able to detect DP signal. It seems that it is due to a capacitor that saturates and needs discharging.

Comment: Thank you, man. I was already ready to buy new video card

Answer (score 0):

I always had to restart windows with the new monitors on, and it would pick it up?

Simple I know but you did not specify if you have tried it, and it does the trick when i move my setup.

Comment: Sorry, did not specify that I tried it, but yes. I done several complete power-down of the computerwith the monitors still powered on. No difference. Going to go buy a new DisplayPoer adater in a little bit, will see if that could be it...